# PSPICE - must be 'I' or 'V' error

Tags: error, pspice

I'm trying to make a super simple circuit simulation for a class, and I keep getting the same error:

```
ERROR -- Must be 'I' or 'V'
```

Here's the whole log:

```
    
**** 03/07/19 15:47:25 *********** Evaluation PSpice (Nov 1999) **************

 * C:\Users\admin\Desktop\FE\Lab1\Schematic1.sch


 ****     CIRCUIT DESCRIPTION


******************************************************************************




* Schematics Version 9.1 - Web Update 1
* Thu Mar 07 15:44:12 2019



** Analysis setup **
.DC LIN V_V1 0 0,75 10m 
--------------------$
ERROR -- Must be 'I' or 'V'
.STEP  TEMP LIST 
+ 20  35


* From [PSPICE NETLIST] section of pspiceev.ini:
.lib "nom.lib"

.INC "Schematic1.net"

**** INCLUDING Schematic1.net ****
* Schematics Netlist *



D_D2         a 0 D1N4002 
V_V1         a 0 0V

**** RESUMING Schematic1.cir ****
.INC "Schematic1.als"



**** INCLUDING Schematic1.als ****
* Schematics Aliases *

.ALIASES
D_D2            D2(1=a 2=0 )
V_V1            V1(+=a -=0 )
_    _(a=a)
.ENDALIASES


**** RESUMING Schematic1.cir ****
.probe


.END
```

Here's an image of the circuit:

[image]

The sim I'm currently running is a DC voltage sweep, from 0 to 0.75, on two temperatures, 20 and 35 degrees.

Any help is appreciated
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use a comma as a decimal separator (e.g. 0,75). SPICE was born in the US and typically expects you to use a period instead.

Comment: +1 mainly because having 7499 rep bothered me but this is the correct answer as well. Interesting how the OP put a period in the second to last sentence but not in their script. Probably either missed the comma button or the period button while typing.